# Wildfly Required services that are not installed:\

Tags: java, jpa, jboss, datasource, wildfly

im trying to deploy a JPA rest application and getting the following error trying to deploy on Wildfly 10.

Error:

```
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:\" => [
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.app.\\\"internal-1.0\\\".newDevConnection\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS\"
    ],
    \"WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => [
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.module.\\\"internal-1.0\\\".\\\"internal-1.0\\\".DefaultDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.ExampleDS]\",
        \"jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"internal-1.0.war#com.e24_MavenProjectTest_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU\\\" is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.\\\"internal-1.0\\\".newDevConnection]\",
        \"jboss.persistenceunit.\\\"internal-1.0.war#com.e24_MavenProjectTest_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU\\\".__FIRST_PHASE__ is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.app.\\\"internal-1.0\\\".newDevConnection]\"
    ]
}"
```

persistance.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="app-pu" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/newDevConnection</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
</persistence-unit>
```

datasource in standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
        <datasource jndi-name="java:/newDevConnection" pool-name="secret" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://secret...</connection-url>
            <driver>mysql</driver>
            <security>
                <user-name>secret</user-name>
                <password>secret</password>
            </security>
        </datasource>
 <drivers>
        <driver name="com.mysql" module="mysql.mysql-connector-java">
          <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
        <driver name="mysql" module="org.mysql">
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
        </driver>
     </drivers>
</datasources>
```

Edit: `mysql jdbc driver` is located in `project/WEB-INF/lib` folder

And what is the difference in an "xa-datasource" and "non-xa-datasource"?

Am i on the right track here? thanks in advance / Marcus

Answer (score 6):

I know it's a year old but in case somebody else hits this question I'll post what I have done for this problem. This took me forever to figure out as new JBOSS Admin.

Short story is the ExampleDS holds a default section in the profile which is where your error is coming from. I normally work with Domain profiles so I'll show the example I have, but Standalone is the same just drop the profile name in front. Default-Bindings is the section in ee subsystem.

```
<default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
```

The default `datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS` is the source of the problem.

You can remove and set the default DataSource to undefined.

```
/profile=Profile_NameHere/subsystem=datasources/data- 
 source=ExampleDS:remove()
/profile=Profile_NameHere/subsystem=ee/service=default-bindings:write- 
 attribute(name=datasource,value=undefined)
```

OR

You can set your own DataSource as the default.

```
/profile=Profile_NameHere/subsystem=ee/service=default-bindings:write- 
 attribute(name=datasource,value=java\:\/jboss\/datasources/name)
```

Comment: Can I avoid creating a standalone.xml ? I don't have one and I know it can works without one, any idea ? :)

Comment: @RomainB. - That is the commands from the JBOSS CLI interface. I found that's the easiest way to update the default bindings.  As to not having a standalone or domain.xml ?? Not sure how the system would work without something like standalone.xml or domain.xml files.  I know you can rename it point it to another custom file with custom config (I have done that in the past).  But of the box standalone.xml and domain.xml are the defaults.

Comment: @RomainB You probably have a version of these but may not realize it.  The configuration files mentioned are under standalone/configuration and domain/configuration.  There are also other configuration files there, for minimal configuration, full configuration, high availability configuration, etc.

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it looks like you deleted the exampleDS wich is needed by other services. So put that section back to datasources.

And XA-Datasource are supporting transactions.

Comment: Why would someone create platform dependencies upon something called "ExampleDS"?

Comment: classic red hat